# JSON Response from Django in Android

Tags: java, android, django, json

I am trying to get a jSON response in Android from my Django based web backend.
The response I am getting is

```
03-19 16:32:32.120: I/System.out(7442): This si the response march API <!doctype html>  <!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->  <!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->  <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->  <head>    <meta charset="utf-8">    <title>ECOM</title>            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge;chrome=1" >    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">            <meta name="description" content="">    <meta name="author" content="">        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />            <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.domain.com/images/logo.png"/>    <meta property="og:title" content="-- description here --"/>    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.domain.com"/>            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/assets/img/favicon.ico" />    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/static/assets/img/apple-touch-icon.png">    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/static/assets/img/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/static/assets/img/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">             <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/assets/css/styles.css" />                    <script src="/static/assets/js/libs/modernizr.custom.60077.js"></script>          <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/assets/css/popup.css" />             <script src="/static/assets/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>           <script src="/static/assets/authentication/js/popup.js"></script>    </head><body><div id="backgroundPopup"></div>      <div class="header" style="text-align:center; padding-top:10px;">       <img src="/static/assets/img/Ecomlogo.png"/>  </div>   <div class="container-fluid" roll="main" id="main">    <div class="span6"><a href="/track_me/scan_open/1/" class="forgotpass pull-right">Track Shipment</a>      <div class="login">        <div class="title">          Login                  </div>                <div class="content-login">          <form action="." method="POST">          <div style='display:none'><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='xpfLvzIES8w6qzpi7kCFp0crWx9aZHGD' /></div>              <input type= "text" name ="username" placeholder="Username" class="user-name"/>            <input type= "Password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>            <input type="submit" class="button-login"/>            <a href="#" class="forgotpass pull-right" id="forgotpass">Forgot Your Password?</a>          </form>        </div>      </div>    </div>    <div class="span6">      <div class="login">        <div class="title">          Ecom Express News                  </div>        <div class="content-login">                  </div>      </div>    </div>  </div>       <!-- modal -->  <div class="modal hide modal-add-revlet" id="add-revlet">    <div class="modal-header">      <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>      <h3>Record</h3>    </div>    <div class="modal-body">          </div>  </div><!--modal end-->   <div id="popupContact">             <a id="popupContactClose">x</a>    </div>        <!-- uncomment pre-deloy -->  <!--<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="assets/js/libs/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>  <!-- bootstrap -->  <script src="/static/assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>  <script src="/static/assets/js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>  <script src="/static/assets/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>  <script src="/static/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>  <script src="/static/assets/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>  <script src="/static/assets/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>  <script src="/static/assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>  <script src="/static/assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>  <script src="/static/assets/js/bootstrap-button.
```

Android Request

```
private String GetPickUpDetails(String pick_up_id2) {

        StringBuilder response  = new StringBuilder();
        String stringUrl=Constants.PICKUP_DETAILS+pick_up_id2+"/";
        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL(stringUrl);

            HttpURLConnection httpconn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            if (httpconn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpconn.getInputStream()),8192);
                String strLine = null;
                while ((strLine = input.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    response.append(strLine);
                }
                input.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("This si the response march API "+response.toString()+" for url"+stringUrl);
        return response.toString();


    }
```

Django Views code

```
def pickup_details(request,id):
        awb_dict={}
    if request.POST:
        print "this is post request",id 
        shipment_records=[]
        shippments=Shipment.objects.filter(pickup_id=id)

        for obj in shippments:
            awb=obj.airwaybill_number
            order_number=obj.order_number
            pincode=obj.pincode
            dest_sc=obj.service_centre
            type=obj.product_type
            if(type == "ccd"):
                col_val=obj.collectable_value
            else:
                col_val=""    
            status=obj.status
            city=obj.destination_city
            act_wt=obj.actual_weight
            dest_SC="hi"
            dest_SC=obj.service_centre
            #dest_SC=String(dest_SC).replace('-',' ')   
            record={"awb":awb,"ordernumber":order_number,"pincode":pincode,"weight":act_wt,"status":status,"city":city,"type":type,"col_value":col_val,"dest_SC":city}
            shipment_records.append(record)

        awb_dict["count"]=len(shipment_records)
        awb_dict["shipments"]=shipment_records
    #else:
         #pass

        return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(awb_dict) )
```

I am not so sure, why I am not getting the expected jSON response. Upon manually hitting the url I am getting the JSON response as expected

**EDIT 1**
I have tried this approach also

```
try{
            URL url = new URL(stringUrl);
            HttpURLConnection httpconn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            if (httpconn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpconn.getInputStream()),8192);
                String strLine = null;
                while ((strLine = input.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    response.append(strLine);
                }
                input.close();
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response.toString();
}
```

**EDIT 2**
The error I am getting is **HTTP 403 Request**  while trying to the sent the request as the value is not reaching the API call

**EDIT 3**
I am getting the HTTP response as 200.The value of `HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();` for the code is `org.apache.http.conn.BasicMangedEntity@4055505d0`

Comment: You appear not to be sending the correct authentication information, and your getting back an error page saying as much.

Comment: Maybe you need to send headers for the request: `"Accept": "application/json"`

Comment: @Perception , pbespechnyi please can you correct me ?

Comment: @onkar, I just googled: http://icfun.blogspot.com/2009/08/java-adding-additional-http-request.html

Comment: Question has been modified. Please look into the matter and do the needful

Comment: Odd that you are getting a 403 instead of a 401, but in any case, like I said before, it looks like the service you are calling requires you to authenticate before retrieving data. You need to find out what form it expects the authentication data to be in, before we can help you further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response was redirecting me to the custom login-page where I had used `@csrf_exempt`.  Further login details were required for code to process the info. I added the login parameter along with my call and the desired response was obtained

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**
`httpconn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");`

---

[HttpURLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)'s default "Accept" HttpHeader value is `text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, /; q=.2`

When `text/html` is used django returns JSON wrapped with HTML. In case when plain JSON is needed, Accept HttpHeader value should be set to `'application/json'`